# asp.net website calling input file from C# code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload

i have ASP web site with input file in it.
i want to take this file with name from this input to my code behind but all time i am getting null for "FileUp1".
this is my code code:

```
ASP:
<input type="file" id="File1" name="File1"/>

C#:
HttpPostedFile FileUp1 = Request.Files["File1"];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your form tag should have `enctype` tag

```
    <form id="form1" runat="server" enctype="multipart/form-data">
....
</form>
```

Input type file should come under this form.

After that you can use same code which you are using currently.

***Sample code***

source page

```
<form id="form1" runat="server" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 <input type="file" id="myFile" name="myFile" />
 <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnUpload" OnClick="btnUploadClick" Text="Upload" />
</form>
```

Code behind C#

```
 protected void btnUploadClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HttpPostedFile file = Request.Files["myFile"];
    if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
    {
        //do your stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: i am getting this error " A page can have only one server-side Form tag." i dont want the input to be server side control also.

Comment: that is correct. a page can have only one form tag! don't add a new form tag just add the `enctype` attribute as i said . Check you are using two form tags in your page remove one.

Comment: in my example input is not the server side it is client side file upload!

Comment: `and if you are using a master page then go to your master page and edit the form tag there,do not add extra form tag on aspx page!!`